# How t0 show $U+W$ and $U\cap W$ are invariant under $T$ if $U$ and $W$ are invariant under $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-theory

Suppose $T:V\to V$ is a linear transformation, how t0 show $U+W$ and $U\cap W$ are invariant under $T$ if $U$ and $W$ are invariant under $T$ ?

My try:

$1.$ Let $u\in U,w\in W$. Then $T(u+w)=T(u)+T(w)$. Since $T(u)\in U,T(w)\in W$, so $T(u+w)\in U+W$. So $T(U+W)\subset U+W$

$2.$ Let $x\in U\cap W$. Then $x\in U$, then $T(x)\in U$. Also $x\in W$ and then $T(x)\in W$. Therefore $T(x)\in U\cap W$. Therefore $T(U\cap W)\subset U\cap W$

I feel my proof too short and a incomplete. Could someone edit?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Your proofs look fine. In this context, however, I don't like the terminology "invariant under $T$", because this should mean $T(U)=U$, not $T(U) \subseteq U$. Better to say "closed under $T$."

Comment: @goblin I think the OP's usage ($T(U) \subseteq U$) is reasonably standard. This is the definition in, e.g. Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* or Lang's *Linear Algebra*, or good old [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace)